# Is there any way to tell Cargo to run its tests on the main thread?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have been trying to build an OpenGL-based image processing library with [GLFW](https://github.com/PistonDevelopers/glfw-rs), and need it to be testable. Unfortunately, I ran into [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/3927) bug - GLFW needs its initialization functions to be called from the main thread, but Cargo tests are run on a background thread.

Comment: Just ran into this trying to use egui, guess it's still not Just Works in 2022?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, to the best of my knowledge, it's not easily possible right now. There is a `--test-threads` argument you can pass to the test harness, but it sets the number of threads in addition to the main thread. So `--test-threads=1` results in two threads still.

---

So you can't really use the default test-harness. Luckily, you can disable it in `Cargo.toml`. Possibly the best solution is to create a new folder (e.g. `gltests`) and place all tests that require being run in main thread in there. Then we just have to declare those tests in `Cargo.toml`:

```
[[test]]
name = "gltests"
path = "gltests/main.rs"
harness = false
```

This means that cargo will try to compile `gltests/main.rs` as an executable (expecting a `main()` function) and execute this executable, whenever you say `cargo test`. This way you won't get any of the fancy output you usually get from cargo tests. You just have to **do everything yourself** in `main.rs`, but at least you can start tests in the main thread.

Comment: Great answer, this also helps anyone writing an automated tests of a desktop GUI application. Just like GLFW in the question, many GUI toolkits also require being initialized or used from the main thread.